# Interpretation of $\int_C \vec A.d\vec r=\int^{(c,d)}_{(a,b)}dN=N(c,d)-N(a-b)$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I don't understand what this line in my textbook is saying. Here's the quote:

If the integrand $\vec A.d\vec r$ is a perfect differential dN, then

$$\int_C \vec A.d\vec r=\int^{(c,d)}_{(a,b)}dN=N(c,d)-N(a-b)$$

Can someone help me interpret this? $\vec A$ is the vector field, $\vec r$ is the vector equation of the line.

By the way, this appears in the 'evaluation of line integrals for plane curves' section of my textbook.

Comment: See this in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Path_independence

Comment: Oh, I see! That was what it was trying to tell me.